# Passing void events from parent component to child component

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, components

## Quick overview

I have a "Terminal" Component which should be able to be used multiple times all over my application. This component should also be able to put into a "read only" mode where you pass a single command you'd like the terminal to fire and it will display the output. I am trying to have this component be able to be refreshed by many things; data updating else where, user events, etc. To achieve this, currently, I am using RxJS subjects as an `@Input` into the terminal component which when updated fires the subscribed functions. This works for the first user click (see bellow) but after that the subject doesn't update again. I suspect this is due to the "object" not updating, there for angular doesn't register the change and my whole idea falls apart.

Can I fix this? or do I need to redesign this "Terminal" component?

## Code

terminal.component.ts

```js
export class TerminalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor() {}

    $destroy = new Subject();
    terminalOutput = '';

    // Command input (if you want the terminal to only fire one command)
    @Input() command = '';
    $command: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');

    // Refresh terminal input
    $refresh: Subject<void> = new Subject();
    @Input() set refresh(value: Subject<void>) {
        this.$refresh = value;
    }

    // ReadOnly Input
    @Input() readOnly = false;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.$refresh
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(this.$destroy),
                tap(() => {
                    const lastCommand = this.$command.getValue();
                    if (lastCommand) {
                        console.log('Refreshing, last command is:', lastCommand);                       
                    }
                })
            )
            .subscribe();

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

parent.component.html

```html
<h1>Home</h1>

<app-terminal command="ls" [refresh]="$refreshSubject"></app-terminal>

<button (click)="refreshTest()">Refresh</button>
```

parent.component.ts

```js
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    $refreshSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject();

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    refreshTest(): void {
        console.log('Refreshing');
        this.$refreshSubject.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check it out that every time you click refresh button then Input setter is called or not  of parent component ?

Comment: I can see on click refresh get called every time https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkc6xx , maybe your $command getting undefined that's why if condition getting failed.

Comment: @HPSingh This stackblitz demo is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, I think there is maybe some small things I'm missing. I should also note I'm using Lazy loading for the parent component but I don't think that would effect if a Subject is getting it's next emit or not

Comment: I also don't think lazy loading would cause any issue, becoz when the route will load it will load both parent and child. So pls try to replicate it first.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem, it was another bug in my code that was causing the RxJS tap to not fire after the first time.

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.$refresh
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(this.$destroy),
                tap(() => {
                    const lastCommand = this.$command.getValue();
                    if (lastCommand) {
                        console.log('Refreshing, last command is:', lastCommand);                       
                        throw new Error("Example Error"); 
                        // ^^^^ This will cause future Subject emits to not fire as this function has failed.
                    }
                })
            )
            .subscribe();

        //...
    }
```

> Side note: I think the question title should be changed to better suit the real problem with my code, and there for have better SEO. However if this is a completely rubbish question then I think it should be deleted.